# awk print is adding a control-m character at end of line

Tags: unix, awk

I am using awk in a bash script and do something like:

```
awk -F, -v result_file=$2'{
print $2 $1 > result_file
}' $data_file
```

In the output file, I am getting a control-M '^M' character at end of each line. What is wrong?

Comment: Your input file might be containing ^M. If so, remove it from there.

Comment: Did you create the data file on a PC? Its line endings are ^M^J, while Unix uses just ^J.

Comment: Set the record separator to CR-LF, i.e. `awk -v RS='\r\n' ...`.

Comment: great...setting record separator worked hansomely... thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The record separator is automatically set to the line-ending of the current system, LF (`\n`) on the Unix-based systems, CR-LF (`\r\n`) on MS systems and CR (`\r`) on Mac OS prior to Mac OS X. So to work on a file recorded on an MS system set the record separator appropriately, in your case:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' ...
```

Comment: Mac OS X is a Unix-like system and uses `\n` line endings.  Mac OS 9 was not based on Unix and used the `\r` line endings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're right, thank you for the correction.